# Issues while using the javax.mail for email content verification using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jakarta-mail, imap

I am trying to set up email verfication for automation using webdriver.This is how I am connecting to the folder using IMAPS.

```
store = session.getStore();
store.connect(host, userName, password);
inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
```

the session is created and while connecting it gets timed out .
here is the Messaging Exception logged:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Read timed out;
nested exception is:
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:479)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
at com.mhs.cm.fitnesse.ui.pages.providers.providers.ProviderEmailVerification.getEmail(ProviderEmailVerification.java:32)
at com.mhs.cm.fitnesse.ui.fixtures.providers.providers.ProviderEmailVerificationFixture.getMailContent(ProviderEmailVerificationFixture.java:17)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at fitnesse.slim.fixtureInteraction.DefaultInteraction.methodInvoke(DefaultInteraction.java:16)

    at fitnesse.slim.MethodExecutor.callMethod(MethodExecutor.java:43)
    at fitnesse.slim.MethodExecutor.invokeMethod(MethodExecutor.java:30)
    at fitnesse.slim.MethodExecutor.findAndInvoke(MethodExecutor.java:52)
```

i tried if I could telnet in to the imaps.google.com and i was able to get in so definitely not an access issue.CAn someone help please?

Comment: Well, what are all your settings and properties?  Gmail must be connected to over TLS.

Comment: Here are the properties that i set:
setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

host:imap.gmail.com
username:xxx
password:yyy

apart from these the others are default.

Comment: What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?  Exactly what telnet command did you use?  Did you run telnet on the same machine as the Java program?  The JavaMail FAQ has more [connection debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).